# Bitmap is rotated by default Android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap, bitmapimage

I had this function to create bitmap, with a suspect behaviour, sometimes, it rotate the created bitmap, there's any way to know if the bitmap is rotated before sending it to my server ?

I test the value of ratio, but not always the root of the issue

```
 private static Bitmap decodeImageFromFiles(String path, Context context) throws FileNotFoundException {

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
            context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.fromFile(new File(path))),
            null,
            options);


    int height = options.outHeight;
    int width = options.outWidth;

    float ratio = width / height;
    Log.e("TAG", "ratio :" + ratio);
    int widthLimit = (int) ((MainActivity) context).getImageWidthValue();

    if (ratio > 0.0)
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, widthLimit, (int) (widthLimit / ratio));
    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    if (ratio >= 1.0) {
        Log.e("TAG", "image is Rotated !");
        matrix.postRotate(90);
        Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        return rotatedBitmap;

    } else return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: Are the bitmaps created by you? or are images from the Media Store which are created by any other app?

Comment: @PerracoLabs yes, I got the path from camera or gallery, then I create the bitmap (sorry)

Comment: Do your images have EXIF information? if yes, then is possible you may need to read if the image is rotated by using the ExifInterface class and checking TAG_ORIENTATION

Comment: it gives me all the time TAG_ORIENTATION = 1, not working in all images

Comment: Do you have an image that could be used for testing? Ideally should be in the original format.

Comment: `it gives me all the time TAG_ORIENTATION = 1,` Then you should all the time rotate it i think.